# How to see result of select during Sql Server debugging

Tags: sql-server

I am debugging a stored procedure in Sql Server, I can see the local variables in "Locals", I can add other variables in "Watches" (I have embedded a picture here with Sql Server in debug mode and different debug windows).
My question is: **where can I see the result of the select statements during debugging**? It is really helpful to see them as they are executed, more so when they read from temporary tables sometimes, which are local to that procedure.
[image]

Later edit:
I have followed the advice given below and am having this problem with XML viewer (please see attachment): "The XML page cannot be displayed"
[image]

Comment: SQL Server Profiler allows you to debug queries, have you looked into this?

Answer (score 1):

From **[`View contents of table variables and temp tables in SSMS debugger`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/details/623353)**:

> This won't be in immediately, but we are considering a feature similar
>   to this for a future release.

And workaround (you need to add additional `XML` variable for each temp table):

```
Declare @TableVar_xml xml
Set @TableVar_xml = (Select * from @TableVar for XML Auto, Elements xsinil);
```

> Then I can look at the table variable contents using the XML viewer.

Comment: Thank you very much, lad2025! Unfortunately I receive an error: "The XML page cannot be displayed" (I have added the print screen in the original question). How do you use XML Viewer, can you please expand a little on this?

Comment: @JD123456 Try: `Set @TableVar_xml = (Select * from @TableVar for XML Auto)`

Comment: @JD123456 Does your `@TableVar` contain any rows?